# How do I search tweets of a given multiple users based on certain criteria using twitter api?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have list of users 
`['foo','bar']`
 I want to search whether they have checked in somewhere or not (using 4sq api)..

So basically, all I am looking for is that whether their tweets contain "`\4sq.com\`"   or not?

I get very confused looking into their api?

Bonus points if the steps can be implemented in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for checking a user's tweets:

One option is to look through the tweets in their User Timeline (accessible in Tweepy through `api.user_timeline`). However, you may have to search through a lot of unrelated Tweets before you come across the one your looking for. Given how many tweets some users have, you might want to only look thorough tweets more recent than a certain date (you can look at the `created_at` attribute of returned tweets).

The other option is to use the Search API (accessible in Tweepy though 'api.search'). This has the advantage of allowing you specify a search query, giving you relevant tweets. However, you will need to search through the tweets until you find one by the user you're looking for. Again, you might want to limit the date range of tweets that you search through.